# What is stage status in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I am learning Git by reading the book "Pro Git", it said there are 3 states in Git they are 'modified', 'Staged' and 'Committed', I just can't understand what stage actually is and when it is used.

I searched on line and find this answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119782/what-stage-means-in-git-source-control, people said 'Staged' gives you better control when you want to partially commit the file.

My question is instead of staging the files for partial commit, can I just commit part of the file I want to and leave the rest of the file as 'modified'? Thus it seems that I don't need a 'Staged' state here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use `git add -i` means "interactive" and select the hunks of changes that should being added to stage and leave those which should not being added to stage. What has been staged can then be committed using `git commit` afterwards.

Comment: So what the 'Stage' here is for?

Comment: Can I say you stage a file means you add the file to commit next time, so at that moment you don't have to add these files again when commit?

Comment: so if I use 'git status' it shows me 3 files are modified, if I use git add 1 and git add 2, 1 and 2 are staged and then I commit, the status now is 1 and 2 are committed but 3 is at the state of 'modified'. If I want to stage file3, I just use 'git add 3' but don't commit this time, is that right?

Comment: yes. or you may even add just a few lines of current changes of 3 to first commit (using `git add -i`) and add other changes in a later commit.

Comment: I understand it now, but feels like this feature is kind of useless, because I can just leave file 3 as modified and add it in the next commit. Do I have some misunderstandins here? thanks.

Comment: No, it is very useful but hard to explain if you never used `git add -i`. Play around with it. You'll see it's benefits in "real-life".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of reading a book, you should go for an interactive git tutorial. In this way you will learn by doing yourself :-)

Have a look at this http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Answer (score 0):

> In a nutshell, you run `git status` to see if anything has been modified
>   and/or staged since your last commit so you can decide if you want to
>   commit a new snapshot and what will be recorded in it.

http://gitref.org/basic/